# How to reference object properties in another module

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python having used C# for many years and I'm hoping someone can help me with this question.  I have a module called actuators.py that contains a number of classes for defining properties and methods for the servos I use in a robot project.  In another module called robot.py, I instantiate my actuators like this:

```
import actuators as Actuators

myActuators = Actuators.AllActuators()
```

This allows me to access the properties of my servos as long as I am in the robot.py module.  For example, I can write:

```
print myActuators.HeadTilt.MinPosition
```

to get the minimum value allowed for the servo that tilts the robot's head.  So far so good.

Now I want to access these same values in a separate thread that is defined by a different module called tilt_head.py. I assume I need to import a reference to the robot.py module, but doing this ends up re-executing all the code in robot.py whereas all I really want is a static reference to the myActuators object.  And I can't use

```
from robot.py import myActuators
```

because myActuators is not a module.

In C#, I would do this using a declaration like this:

```
public static Actuators myActuators;
```

which then allows me to reference myActuators in any other file within my project.  Is there a way to do something similar in Python?  If you need my actual code, I will be happy to post it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a word of clarification and terminology. Python doesn't have "properties" in the same sense that C# does.  It does have methods, and it calls its data members "attributes".  Through its extensive dynamic programming ability, you can hack out something that behaves like C# properties if you need them.  I think here, you just mean data members/attributes.

Answer (score 2):

> And I can't use
>
> ```
> from robot.py import myActuators
> ```
>
> because myActuators is not a module.

But `myActuators` doesn't need to be a module. You can do exactly that. (Though you'll want to use just `robot` rather than `robot.py`)

http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

As well:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules

"A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the first time the module is imported somewhere."

So using a script that imports `robot` and then `tilt_head`, the executable stuff in `robot.py` will NOT be run multiple times.

Of course, if `robot.py` is intended to be the main module of the program, then I'd suggest going with A. Levy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use:

```
from robot import myActuators
```

You can't say "from robot.py" because the name there is a module name, not a file name.

BTW: I'm not sure why you are doing `import actuators as Actuators`.  Why do you want to change the case?  Modules are most commonly lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

As others have been saying, you can actually import myActuators from the robot module. To solve your problem of the code in robot being re-executed, the standard Python approach is to wrap the stand-alone code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` so that it will only be executed when the module is used as a standalone app, but not when it is imported.

E.G.

```
# Things that are defined when robot.py is used as a module
# and when used standalone.
import actuators as Actuators

myActuators = Actuators.AllActuators()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Stuff that you only want executed when running robot.py
```

Then when you want to use robot.py in another module, you should be able to do this:

```
from robot import myActuators
```

## EDIT:

Actually, as [JAB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138772/jab) pointed out, I was a little confused in my explanation of conditional execution. your code won't be re-executed if you reload the module. The module loading machinery handles reloading of modules to make sure that they only get loaded and defined one time. All subsequent loads are references to the previously loaded module. If, however, you do have some steps that you only want to happen when you are running the module as a script, then you can place them in the if block and they won't be executed when you load robots from another module.

I guess it doesn't really solve your problem, though it seems like your problem was really an incorrect import syntax.

Comment: Not quite correct. If a module with executable code is imported somewhere in a program, and you later import another module that imports the first module, the executable code will NOT be re-executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you can access that object as robot.myActuators because it already exists in the process, inside the robot.py namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the answers and pointers.  As it turns out, my problem was a recursive import that ended up trying to create an object more than once.  By sorting out the instance creation a little more logically, I was finally able to make the problem go away.